# Coredata Migration, mapping table appending string and accessing different entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to migrate core data model using the mapping model.
Is it possible to map a destination entity to multiple source entity, for example get value from one table and then get value from another table?

Also it is possible to append an value to the data for example if I am mapping a variable
Path > "/Documents/Test/",$source.ID

Answer (score 0):

No idea about your first query, never tried it. Have done the reverse though.

For your second query, write the code below as your 'Value Expression' in the mapping

```
FUNCTION("/Documents/Test/", "stringByAppendingFormat:" , "%d", $source.ID)
```

You may have to adjust the format specifiers and/or the selector name depending on type of '$source.ID'. I had used this when I added a 'name' attribute to one of the entities and wanted to assign a default value to it like 'Page x' during migration. It took me a while to get the syntax right though.